# JSON with JAXB using Maven

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I am using Jersey (with Jetty) and Maven to implement a RESTful service. I am trying to send a JSONObject using JAXB, I have followed some tutorials such as: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/1.7/user-guide.html#d4e919 and http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html

So I just have a simple bean that I want to send as a JSON Object. I have followed all the steps, but I am not able to send the JSON Object (although I do recieve the XML format correctly). I obtain the following exception: *com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class de.vogella.jersey.jaxb.model.Todo, and Java type class de.vogella.jersey.jaxb.model.Todo, and MIME media type application/json was not found*

I have tried different solutions that I found around, but nothing seems to work. 
I am wondering if I must have any dependencies missing or I have to implement a ContextResolver (although any tutorials use them for easy objects like these ones).

These are the dependencies that I have:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jetty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.26</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the missing dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And I had to add a repository as well to avoid missing archetypes errors:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
        <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Are running on non-Oracle JDK? Haven't thought about that. Oracle JDK bundles JAXB RI out of the box, so you should not need the eclipse link (alternative JAXB impl.) dependency.